# First Sound not played on ViewPager until swipes the page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am learning android development as after watching tutorials I have created this app where image is swiping using viewpager. But now if i want play different sound on each image swipe? Is it possible in this . This is my code

PageIndicatiorActivity

```
   package com.horizontalscrollviewwithpageindicator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class PageIndicatorActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(player);
    }

    private int[] mAudio = new int[]{R.raw.one,R.raw.two,R.raw.three,R.raw.four,R.raw.five,R.raw.six,R.raw.seven,R.raw.eight,R.raw.nine,R.raw.ten};

    private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.no1,R.drawable.no2,R.drawable.no3,R.drawable.no4,R.drawable.no5,R.drawable.no6,R.drawable.no7,R.drawable.no8,R.drawable.no9,R.drawable.no10};

 OnPageChangeListener player = new OnPageChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0)
        {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(PageIndicatorActivity.this, mAudio[arg0]);
            mp.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
        {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you let your `Activity` or your `Adapter` implement the `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` interface.

**http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html**

Have a look at the methods of the interface and implement your "sound" there.

```
 @Override
 public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onPageSelected(int position) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

 }
```

Comment: This is an example with code :)
What in particular do you want to know in addition to that?

Comment: see i have tried to do this. see i have just udated my code. Now it s working but however i have set onPageChangeListener so sound comes when page change but it remains mute on first page ofcourse there is no page change when application loads. but iwant to play sound from the first image..

Answer (score 0):

SuRaj Prince, reverse the order of calls and it should work, so first set the ChangeListener, then call setCurrentItem.

Additionally, if you play only short sounds, use SoundPool instead of MediaPlayer.

Comment: no it still remains the same problem. I want to play sound from beginning but it is not playing first sound rest all are fine

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code which works fine now

```
public class Numbers extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    MediaPlayer BG;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(player);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        BG = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
        BG.setLooping(true);
        BG.setVolume(100, 100);
        BG.start();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this, mAudio[0]);
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        BG.pause();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    BG.start();
    }

    private int[] mAudio = new int[]{R.raw.one,
                                     R.raw.two,
                                     R.raw.three,
                                     R.raw.four,
                                     R.raw.five,
                                     R.raw.six,
                                     R.raw.seven,
                                     R.raw.eight,
                                     R.raw.nine,
                                     R.raw.ten};

    private int imageArra[] =  {R.drawable.no1,
                                R.drawable.no2,
                                R.drawable.no3,
                                R.drawable.no4,
                                R.drawable.no5,
                                R.drawable.no6,
                                R.drawable.no7,
                                R.drawable.no8,
                                R.drawable.no9,
                                R.drawable.no10};

    public  OnPageChangeListener player = new OnPageChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg1)
        {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this, mAudio[arg1]);
        mp.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
        {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.numbers, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```